# How to update, insert, delete in Content Provider without generating notification?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have written a Custom Content Provider on top of a SQLite Database. The Content Provider extends [SQLiteContentProvider](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.2_r1.1/com/android/providers/calendar/SQLiteContentProvider.java/?v=source). The content provider send notifications at the end of many insert, delete or update operations. Now I wish to do a few update, insert and delete operation on Database but does not want any notification to be generated. How to achieve this?

Code sample from `SQLiteContentProvider#bulkInsert`

```
@Override
    public int bulkInsert(Uri uri, ContentValues[] values) {
        int numValues = values.length;
        mDb = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        mDb.beginTransactionWithListener(this);
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < numValues; i++) {
                Uri result = insertInTransaction(uri, values[i]);
                if (result != null) {
                    mNotifyChange = true;
                }
                mDb.yieldIfContendedSafely();
            }
            mDb.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } finally {
            mDb.endTransaction();
        }

        onEndTransaction();
        return numValues;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using a different URI when calling update/insert/delete that you don't want notifications for

so you'll have `YourMetadata.CONTENT_URI` and `YourMetadata.CONTENT_URI_DONT_NOTIFY`

Then you can perform your inserts/updates/deletes as normal.. just before you notify check to see if your uri is one that you shouldn't notify on

If you have a URI matcher you can use the code from the match result to determine which URI you did a bulk insert on

If not you can use

```
boolean notifyChanges = YourMetadata.CONTENT_URI.equals(uri); //will be true if we want to notify on the URI
```

then use the value of notifyChanges after you insert to determine if you want to notify or not.

Comment: I have edited the question, bulkInsert method does not use Uri.

Comment: ok I was wrong, could you edit the code of `bulkInsert` to effect the changes you are suggesting.

Comment: I also found that `SQLiteContentProvider#applyBatch` does not send `notification`

Comment: You will have to do the same thing for that method. However since you're not directly passed a URI you'll have to get the URI from each of the ContentProviderOperation objects you are passed using Uri uri = operations.getUri()

Comment: Ok, Thanks, you have very deep knowledge on the subject.